# Data not inserted into table

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I have a problem, I have a Stored procedure insert query and a PHP Form... I need to save fname and lname to my table by calling the stored procedure in my PHP. I didnt get any errors when i click the button but when i look into my table... there were no data inserted...

PHP code:

```
<?php

$serverName = " BONGBONG-PC ";  
$connection = array( "Database"=>"benefit_insurance"); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connection); 


$btn=$_POST['button']; 
$s_fname=$_POST['fname']; 
$s_lname=$_POST['lname']; 


$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare ($conn,'CALL insert_record(@fname, @lname)', array(&$s_fname,&$s_lname)); 

 sqlsrv_execute ($stmt);

  if( !$stmt ) { 
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
  } 

  echo "<script language=javascript>alert('ACCOUNT SAVED')</script>";


 ?>
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="login_body">
<form method="post" name="MyForm">

<p class="p3"> First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="fname" class="aaa"/> </p>
<p class="p4"> Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="lname" class="aaa"/> </p>

<input type="submit" name="button" class="login" value="LOGIN"/>
</form>
</div>
```

STORED PROCEDURE in SQL SERVER

```
USE [benefit_insurance]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_record] 
 @fname varchar(50) output,
 @lname varchar(50) output
AS
BEGIN
insert into trylang (fname,lname) values (@fname,@lname)


END
```

Comment: Technology information belongs in the tags, not in your question title. I've made my best effort with re-titling, but you may want to improve it further.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking for errors on the execute statement, only on the prepare statement.

(And storing passwords plain text is a big No No)

Comment: can u show me how to do it please... ive been figuring this out for 4 days

Comment: Ive checked the errors already but still no data saved on my db

Answer (score 0):

The if statement here:

```
sqlsrv_execute ($stmt);
if( !$stmt ) { ...
```

Checks whether your *statement* is `true`. Given that it's not an empty string or `0`, that will always be so.

You ought to be checking the *return* value from `sqlsrv_execute`:

```
if(!sqlsrv_execute ($stmt)) { ...
```